# How to display error message when using a grade calculator in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Below is a grade calculator that will attach a letter grade to the number entered, using if/else statements. I am having trouble finding a way to display an error message if an out of ranger number or non numeric value is entered. Any suggestions? Thanks!

```
    var entry;
    var letterGrade;

    entry = prompt("Enter number grade from 0 through 100\n" +
                   "Or enter 999 to end entries", 999);
    entry = parseInt(entry);

if (entry <= 59)
    letterGrade = "F";
else if (entry >= 60 && entry <= 69)
    letterGrade = "D";
else if (entry >= 70 && entry <= 79)
    letterGrade = "C";
else if (entry >= 80 && entry <= 89)
    letterGrade = "B";
else if (entry >= 90 && entry <= 100)
    letterGrade = "A";

    alert("Number grade = " + entry + "\n" +
          "Letter grade = " + letterGrade);
```

Comment: Try adding `}else{//Error here }` I would also recommend using `{` and `}` to make it easier to see opening/closing on your if condition. Use the `}else{` will allow you to return an error is the above conditions are not met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your out of range would be anything >100 so you can cover that with an else in the end:

```
[..]
else if (entry >= 90 && entry <= 100)
    letterGrade = "A";
else
    alert("Error, your number " + entry + " was out of range (>100)");
```

As for it not being a number, you can use isNaN():

```
if(isNaN(entry)){
    alert("That was not a number!");
else {
    if (entry <= 59)
        letterGrade = "F";
    ....
}
```

Edit: I see your input is >0<101 so to catch negative numbers you would need to add this to your first if statement:

```
if (entry >= 0 && entry <= 59)
```

Comment: This works! The alert for an out of range number works great, but the second alert still pops right after. Is there a way for that to not happen, or even bring up the initial prompt?

Comment: To fix it you need to include your alert in your if statements. So if(entry >= 0 && entry <= 59) { letterGrade = "F"; alert("Number grade = "....); } (notice how it's within the if's curly brackets. To read more about this concept, read a basic tutorial on how scopes work. This phenomenon applies to functions, classes and what not as well, and are an important concept in programming :)

Answer (score 0):

Add a check in the beginning to see if `entry` is a valid input:

```
if(isNaN(entry) || entry < 0 || entry > 100)
    alert('Only a grade between 0 and 100 is allowed');
```

```js
var entry
,   letterGrade;

entry = parseInt(prompt("Enter number grade from 0 through 100\n" +
                   "Or enter 999 to end entries", 999));
if(isNaN(entry) || entry < 0)
    alert('Only a grade between 0 and 100 is allowed');
else if (entry <= 59)
    letterGrade = "F";
else if (entry >= 60 && entry <= 69)
    letterGrade = "D";
else if (entry >= 70 && entry <= 79)
    letterGrade = "C";
else if (entry >= 80 && entry <= 89)
    letterGrade = "B";
else if (entry >= 90 && entry <= 100)
    letterGrade = "A";

    alert("Number grade = " + entry + "\n" +
          "Letter grade = " + letterGrade);
```